# As of August 2017, is there a way to get *good* sound and/or video on raspberry pi 3 through airplay for iOS 8+?

Tags: audio, streaming-video, streaming, ios

Kodi's airplay doesn't work. Is there a way to get kodi's airplay working with iOS 8+? If it's not possible with kodi, is there another good alternative for iOS 8+?

Answer (score 1):

Yes and/or no.

Yes, there is a good solution for streaming sound over AirPlay with [shairport-sync](https://github.com/mikebrady/shairport-sync). You don't need Kodi for that.

No, there is still no good solution for video streaming. :(

Comment: i tried shairport from this project http://makezine.com/projects/raspberry-pi-airplay-speaker/ and it sounded horrible with a very high pitch

Comment: but I see that you pointed you another repository. I used https://github.com/hendrikw82/shairport.git

Comment: The one you pointed out seems to be much more recent. Right now I'm trying OSMC and if it doesn't work I'll try the repository you pointed out.

Comment: Shairport-sync has the ability to synchronize speakers and allows for multi-room streaming from iTunes. As I also forked the repository for my own project I know that it does not alter the sound in any way. So I suggest you check your speaker. Also don't forget to set the volume to 0.0dB in `alsa-mixer`.

Comment: OSMC worked. The lasted rasbpian with Kodi didn't. I'll stick to OSMC for now.

Comment: Does it work for video, too?

Comment: Sorry I was mistaken. It doesn't seem to be working when I try to connect from macOS Sierra or from spotify on iOS 10. It only works using Airfoil on macOS.

Comment: Does Shairport-sync works in the other scenarios too?

Comment: I use El Capitan and there it works as a system speaker and from iTunes as multi-room speaker. With my iPhone SE it just works.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I'll definitely try it out.

Comment: It's still making a very high pitch noise for like 5 seconds. It stops and afterwards begin again. Any ideas how to solve it? Is that the solution: "Also don't forget to set the volume to 0.0dB in alsa-mixer"?? How should I do it?

Comment: It's something with the mac connection. It works perfectly from iPhone and AirFoil. I have macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Comment: ssh into your RPi and run `alsamixer`. There you can increase the volume with the arrow up and arrow down buttons. Anyway what you describe is the low volume limit of the RPi. So you should try to increase the volume on your Mac. The RPi has a noticeable "hiss" on low volume especially since Model B+ and newer. A cheap USB-Soundcard can give a significant improvement. For high fidelity you can consider HiFi-Berry.